# Number of ways of assigning jobs to a group (simple counting)

Tags: combinatorics

We have 4 different jobs to be done, and a group of 12 people from which to choose workers. How many different ways are there to choose 3 workers for the 4 jobs assuming that one worker does two jobs?

My thinking is that there are ${12}\choose{3}$ ways of choosing the 3 people from the group. Then there are $4\choose2$ ways of selecting two jobs to be merged into one job. Finally there are $3!$ ways to distribute jobs to the chosen people, so the product of these numbers should be the answer.

Is this correct? Is there a different approach for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that’s fine. There are slightly different ways of thinking about it. For instance, you could start by selecting the two jobs to be assigned to one person; as you say, that can be done in $\binom42$ ways. Call the other jobs $J$ and $K$. Now you can pick one of the $12$ for the double job, one of the remaining $11$ for $J$, and one of the remaining $10$ for $K$, for a total of $$\binom42\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10$$ ways of assigning the jobs. Of course

$$\binom{12}33!=12\cdot11\cdot10\;,$$

so this isn’t really all that much different from your approach.

Or you could *really* stretch it out by first choosing the person to get two jobs, then choosing his pair of jobs, then choosing a person to get one job, then choosing his job, and finally choosing the third worker, who will of course get the only remaining job:

$$12\cdot\binom42\cdot11\cdot2\cdot10\;.$$

But all of these approaches are pretty similar: it’s just a question of the order in which you make the choices.

Comment: I appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: @RR: You’re welcome.